# "Connection with adb was interrupted." Have tried EVERYTHING

Tags: android, eclipse, adb, adt

> Connection with adb was interrupted. 0 attempts have been made to
>   reconnect. You may want to manually restart adb from the Devices view.

I keep getting this error message EVERY TIME I try to run my code which worked fine on a pre-format installation.  Now that I'm on a fresh set-up, I get this every single time.  I've tried using both emulated android devices and my phone connected by USB and I get the same error regardless.  The emulator starts fine when I start it manually, I can capture screens from it and stuff via the DDMS perspective (same with my phone), I just can't actually get adb to do anything.

I've tried literally every suggestion offered here on Stack Exchange.  I've restarted adb many times in every way possible (task manager, command prompt, via the DDMS interface), I've disabled every bit of firewall / anti-virus software that could possibly interfere.  I've checked for latest updates for ADT and eclipse, I've tried various different versions of both, I've removed every trace of ADT / eclipse from my PC and re-installed with a fresh copy.  I've disabled IPv6 and added various launch options attempting to solve the problem.

I am literally completely out of options.  If anyone has any suggestions I would be eternally grateful.

Comment: Have you checked if your phone connects correctly otherwise? With that I mean: does it synchronize your address book correctly, do programs like Android Commander work right?

Comment: @DigCamara - ADB and end-user interface drivers are not necessarily related.  The stated problem also extends to the emulator, to it's probably unrelated to specific device end-user functionality, unless installing end-user drivers has broken the SDK tools.

Comment: You might try working with ADB from the command line.

Comment: @ChrisStratton you're right: that's why I mentioned Android Commander which does use ADB to connect.

Comment: Hi, yes my phone seems to work without a problem in every other circumstance I've tried (mass storage, pushing and pulling stuff in Android commander and such).  Thanks for the response.

Comment: Try starting up Eclipse and then type "adb devices" into the command prompt

Comment: Also worth mentioning:  When I first start Eclipse I always receive the following error;  "Failed to initialize Monitor Thread:  Unable to establish loopback connection"

Comment: adb devices does seem to correctly display my phone as connected  (the emulator is not running currently)

Comment: What OS are you working with? It may be a problem with Eclipse's permissions

Comment: Windows 7 x64.  I have run Eclipse as administrator, though haven't delved in to any more complex permissions that may be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

if you so say that you have tried every thing..
i'd say the only option is to save your projects and completely replace the adt bundle..
i had a similar problem..
suffered for two days then took my projects in my pen drive dumped the adt bundle and downloaded it again..
i don't think there's any other way..
hope i help

Comment: Hello, well funnily enough this is more or less what I've done a couple times now, I've tried both the 64bit and 32bit version of the ADT bundle and had no luck.  But thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: thats very wierd..
are you connecting your phone before using adt??

Comment: Have tried both connecting my phone before starting eclipse, connecting it after start eclipse, and not connecting it at all (using emulator).  All give the same error.

Comment: Having exhausted everything else I can think of I'm going to completely format the computer and install nothing but the ADT bundle.  If the problem still persists I guess it must be some obscure hardware issue...?  I'll report back with results.

Comment: well..
for what i know is that windows update dont go hand in hand with eclipse..
so formatting may work..

however..good luck for that

Answer (score 0):

For this problem ask many question but not solve it......
you must go to oracle site for download jdk last version 
do install two part of install action in drice c:
or default way fro install jdk be c:....
Restart the your PC then start eclips ide ....

Answer (score 0):

Three ways, u can try every method until u are successful:

1. close and reopen Eclipse ; or restart cellphone ; or restart computer(OMG, i do it very much)
2. update ur ADT to 22. I do resolve this problem via this method, although i am not sure this is the exact way to resolve it.
3. my colleague taught me another method: press win+r (if ur os is Windows), type "services.msc", and find  the "windows module installer" service , open it. then restart ur computer.